# Show/Hide div using classes and masonry

Tags: jquery, hide, show, jquery-masonry

I looked at the existing question and didn't find anything that fixed my problem.
Im using masonry to display content accordingly to filters.

Im using JS to hide and show entire classes and reload the masonry of the container:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#allvfx').click(function(){
      $('.itemfilm').hide();
      $('.item').show();
      $('#container').masonry();
});


$('#allfilms').click(function(){
      $('.item').hide();
      $('.itemfilm').show();
      $('#container').masonry();
 }); 

});
```

the problem is that when clicking on the first filter "allvfx" everything works, but then using the second filter "allfills" makes everything freeze.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I can't see a reason straight away without testing some code... could you put up a jsfiddle? That said, you're not making best use of the Masonry api to handle this and 9 jQuery objects where 1 would have done makes me sad :-(

Comment: would love to learn. (Im currently trying to improve my skills and I got a lot of work to)

Im just looking for a way to filter/sort items so I could display all of them, category 1, or category 2.